# Jquery Icons fly-In animate effect onload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need fly-in effects of image icons during page onload.

Kindly check the below images, first image was icons should in different directions during page load and it should animate and arrange in the div positions like second image.

Any idea would be much helpful..

[image]

[image]

Comment: what should happen if they have a larger or smaller screen?

Comment: thanks for the reply Aram.  Actually the layout is for 1024X768 only. Initially all the icons are splitted some where around the layout and once the page onload, it should fly-in to their locations.

Answer (score 0):

The effect itself is not the real problem.You can set all elements that should fly in to position absolute and set their position out of the screen an then animate them to the right position.

The real problem will be to make it working with different screen sizes without destroying the layout.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion sven.  For a single icon i can make it to move different position initially [For ex., top left] and then during onload i animate it to original div position.  But, here there are many icons and i need to make them different directions  initially. This is where i am not getting any idea...:(

Comment: You don't need to set the direction for the animation. You only need to set a start position for every icon and animate them to the end position. You could for example set every icon on a start position per css and give the element itself data-* attributes with the end coordinates. Then you put all elements in an array, loop through and animate them from start-point to end-point. With this method you don't need to write an extra animation for every icon you need only one animation-function tht takes over the end points from the data-* attributes.

Comment: thanks sven. these icons is not a fixed one. Sometimes there will be 12icons [3rows X 4cols] and sometimes 16icons [4X4] or 9 icons[3X3]...

Comment: That you could also automatically determine over a mathematical function.You will see as soon as you start implementing the functionality step by step it is not as hard as you might think in the moment.

Comment: yes sven, you are correct, i think , i am on a right track. progressing well...  thanks...

Comment: Hi , it is working properly in firefox, but not in IE,chrome. [ http://jsfiddle.net/CuV2U/2/  ]

Comment: For analyzing that problem you need t show some code, or better a fiddle.

Comment: Yes sven, i added fiddle link in my previous comment, plz check here.. [ http://jsfiddle.net/CuV2U/2/ ]

Comment: set the position of your li to relative and then change the top and left from that position to your wished start-point. From there you animate to 0 / 0